# How to add vertical short-lines around amCharts Bullets?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, data-visualization, amcharts

For amCharts Line Chart, is it possible to add vertical lines around Bullets? Is it feasible at all? I have already checked Stock/OHLC Chart, but the requirement is vertical lines should be straight similar to below.

- Green short-line for Income
- Red short-line for Expenses
- Y-axis is Revenue in Millions

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

[image: l]

Comment: JSFiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/vghe08tw/6/

Answer (score 0):

I would add two column graphs, red and green, with open and value fields specified.